# gen_server and the run-time errors

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

I have a run-time error in the init part of a gen_server.
- Init begin by process_flag(trap_exit,true)
- gen_server is part of a supervision tree
I try to print the reason in the terminate module but it seems to exit elsewhere.
- why terminate is not called ?
The application stops with shutdown as reason. 
- How and where to catch the run-time error ?

Comment: First of all, it's a general question !

Comment: The question is general, but your idea is correct. Normally, `terminate` is called. This is why people ask for code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `terminate` callback is normally called in this situation, namely because you have trapped exits.

The only place where this is not the case is if the crash happens in the init-function. In that case, the responsibility is on the supervisor, who usually terminates itself as a result. Then this error crawls up the supervisor tree until it ends up terminating your whole application.

Usually, the supervisor will log a supervisor report with the context set to `start_error`. This is your hint that the part of the supervision tree has problems you should handle. You should check for this, because you may have the wrong assumption on where the error occurs.

**EDITED FROM HERE**

Your problem is that you don't know about SASL at all. Study it. Here is an example of how to use it.

Hoisted code from your example:

First, the bahlonga needed to tell Erlang we have a gen_server.

```
-module(foo).
-behaviour(gen_server).
-export([start_link/0]).
-export([init/1, handle_call/3, handle_cast/2, handle_info/2,
     terminate/2, code_change/3]).
```

We hack the #state{} record so it can be used with your code

```
-record(state, { name, port, socket_listen }).
```

Basic start_linkage...

```
start_link() ->
    gen_server:start_link({local, foo}, ?MODULE, [], []).
```

Your init function, spawn problem included.

```
init([]) ->
    Port = 3252,
    Name = "foo",
```

Above we have hacked a bit for the sake of simplification...

```
    process_flag(trap_exit, true),
    erlang:error(blabla),
    Opts = [binary, {reuseaddr, true},
        {backlog,5}, {packet, 0}, {active, false}, {nodelay, true}],
    case gen_tcp:listen(Port,Opts) of
    {ok,Socket_Listen} ->
        logger:fmsg("--> [~s,init] Socket_Listen crée = ~p",
            [Name,Socket_Listen]),
        {ok,handle_accept(#state{socket_listen=Socket_Listen})};
    {error, Reason} ->
        logger:fmsg("--> [~s,init] Erreur, Raison =~p",
            [Name,Reason]), {stop, Reason}
    end.
```

Hacks for missing functions....

```
handle_accept(_) ->
    #state{}.
```

The rest is just the basics..., so I omit them.

Now for `foo_sup` the supervisor for `foo`:

```
-module(foo_sup).
-behaviour(supervisor).
-export([start_link/0]).
-export([init/1]).
-define(SERVER, ?MODULE).
```

Basic start link...

```
start_link() ->
    supervisor:start_link({local, ?SERVER}, ?MODULE, []).
```

Basic ChildSpec. Get the foo child up and running...

```
init([]) ->
    FooCh = {foo, {foo, start_link, []},
         permanent, 2000, worker, [foo]},
    {ok, {{one_for_all,0,1}, [FooCh]}}.
```

Boot Erlang with SASL enabled:

```
 jlouis@illithid:~$ erl -boot start_sasl
 Erlang R14B02 (erts-5.8.3) [source] [64-bit] [smp:2:2] [rq:2] [async-threads:0] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

 =PROGRESS REPORT==== 9-Dec-2010::01:01:51 ===
 [..]
 Eshell V5.8.3  (abort with ^G)
```

Let us try to spawn the supervisor...

```
 1> foo_sup:start_link().
```

And we get this:

```
=CRASH REPORT==== 9-Dec-2010::01:05:48 ===
  crasher:
    initial call: foo:init/1
    pid: <0.58.0>
    registered_name: []
    exception exit: {blabla,[{foo,init,1},
                             {gen_server,init_it,6},
                             {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3}]}
```

Above we see that we have a crash in `foo:init/1` due to an exception `blabla`.

```
      in function  gen_server:init_it/6
    ancestors: [foo_sup,<0.45.0>]
    messages: []
    links: [<0.57.0>]
    dictionary: []
    trap_exit: true
    status: running
    heap_size: 233
    stack_size: 24
    reductions: 108
  neighbours:
```

And now the supervisor gets to report about the problem!

```
=SUPERVISOR REPORT==== 9-Dec-2010::01:05:48 ===
     Supervisor: {local,foo_sup}
     Context:    start_error
```

The context is *exactly* as I said it would be...

```
     Reason:     {blabla,[{foo,init,1},
                          {gen_server,init_it,6},
                          {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3}]}
```

And with the expected reason.

```
     Offender:   [{pid,undefined},
                  {name,foo},
                  {mfargs,{foo,start_link,[]}},
                  {restart_type,permanent},
                  {shutdown,2000},
                  {child_type,worker}]
```

Comment: I emulate a runtime error in init with erlang:error(blabla) and I never see blabla in the supervisor !

Comment: init(State=#state{port=Port,name=Name}) ->
process_flag(trap_exit, true),
erlang:error(blabla),
Opts = [binary, 
       {reuseaddr, true},
       {backlog,5},
       {packet, 0},
       {active, false},
       {nodelay, true}],  
       case gen_tcp:listen(Port,Opts) of
  {ok,Socket_Listen}->
 logger:fmsg("--> [~s,init] Socket_Listen crée = ~p",[Name,Socket_Listen]), 
  {ok,handle_accept(State#state{socket_listen=Socket_Listen})};
  
  {error, Reason} ->
   logger:fmsg("--> [~s,init] Erreur, Raison = ~p",[Name,Reason]),
         {stop, Reason}
 end.

Comment: Please add this code to your original question and try to format it a bit. My eyes are in pain.

Comment: Now with explanation of the problem. You need to enable SASL on your Erlang.

Comment: As you said, I must learn SASL ! Thank you for this example.
And I must find how to start it because I am using EMACS or Erlide ...